# Silverlight, DataTemplate, Binding to click event

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, listbox, datatemplate

Good day,

I'm getting desperate here. Consider the following use case.

I have a listbox which item's are custom templated control. It has several buttons for which this custom control has event handlers in code behind. Whenever button is clicked I call a method of the object my custom control is bound to through the DataContext. So, when user clicks stop, I call _context.stopDownload() and object does the rest.

But, I have one button which should start the playback of the content. I am trying to somehow listen to this button's click event on the core level, not in the code behind of my custom control which represents listbox's item UI.

So, to summarize:

1. I have a core object which loads list of items into observable collection.
2. This core object then gets the listbox object using GetTemplateChildnren. When this is done, core sets the ItemsSource of the listbox control to observable collection I get on #1 step. The listbox gets rendered with custom template control as its item's (DataTemplate used).
3. I need to link event handler on the core object's level to the button element of custom control inside the DataTemplate.

I can't figure out #3. Among other things, I've tried doing something like that after I set the ItemsSource to wire the event handler, but container is always null.

```
DownloadsListElement.ItemsSource = _downloadsList;

foreach (var item in DownloadsListElement.ItemsSource)
{
    var container = DownloadsListElement.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as     FrameworkElement;
}
```

I have also tried button a grid over the listbox and trying to get button clicked using VisualTreeHelper on Grid's MouseLeftButtonDown/Up, but those are never invoked when I click on the button.

I'm thinking that only possible solution would be using some kind of commands pattern when I register event handler in some global object and then call it from the custom control inside the DataTemplate.

I'm out of the ideas and hope someone had something similar to this issue.

Thank you.

**Update**

Thanks to McGamagle and ChrisW I got it working. The final code I have on the button looks like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ListBoxExt}}" MethodName="PlayButton_Click"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Throw `ClickMode="Press"` on your Button in the template and you should get your event to fire off whatever.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see how this solves my problem. May I ask you to clarify? I have a custom control inside the DataTemplate and this custom control has a button. I need to be able to wire event handler to this button outside of the custom control. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I thought you were having trouble receiving your click event to the Button that sits inside the DataTemplate for your ListBox items. Can you not just just set the DataContext explicitly?

Comment: Sorry, can you show your though in code? The DataContext is set on the listbox when I set its ItemsSource. I just want to understand how to bind an event handler to the control inside DataTemplate. If this is not possible, I guess I will be using some global messages or something (pub/sub patern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to attach a handler to an item inside a ListBox item's DataTemplate, where the handler belongs to the parent's DataContext.

You can do this using a `RelativeSource FindAncestor` binding.  You might want to consider using an `ICommand` instead of a handler, but if you do need a handler, then you can use the Blend SDK's [`CallMethodAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

The XAML should look something like this (where "SomeCommand" is an `ICommand` property of the ListBox's data context):

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox},
                                      Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Or using the "CallMethodAction" technique (here "HandleButtonClick" must be a public method of the ListBox's data context):

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction 
                            TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}" 
                            MethodName="HandleButtonClick" />
                    </i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Dang, as I'm sitting here typing... +1

Comment: @ChrisW. ha, sorry -- you should post your answer anyway though, or did you have literally the same idea?

Comment: Yea just reaching the path with the datacontext, pretty much the same thing since it's generally how I do it anyway lol

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and prompt responses guys!