# Binding click handler inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

I want to bind a gridview-click inside a DataTemplate element. I have to use the DataTemplate element as it is necessary for HubSections.

If I bind this command inside the DataTemplate element, I'm getting an error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
<Frame x:Name="frame">
  <Hub VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
     <HubSection Width="250" x:Name="section1"  IsHeaderInteractive="True" >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="{x:Bind MainPageVM.click}">
                            <RelativePanel>
                                <Image x:Name="image" Source="Assets/1.png" Width="Auto" Height="250"  />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="page1" Text="page1" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </GridView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>

                //....
         </Hub>             
</Frame>
```

However, if I bind the same handler outside a DataTemplate element (for example HubSectionHeaderClick) it is working fine.

But I don't understand why?  And what options do I have to solve this?

**Edit:**
Here the XAML with the ElementName:

```
<Hub VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ThisIsHub" >
```

and the Binding:

```
Binding ElementName=ThisIsHub, Path=DataContext.click
```

getting the error:

> Cannot resolve property "click" in data context of type 'object'

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232849/silverlight-datatemplate-binding-to-click-event)  problem seems to be similar, but doesn't work under UWP/Win10.

Comment: I guess Data context of dstatemplate is different

Comment: Give hub control   a name. Use this binding {Binding  ElementName=''Hubrlelement'',Path="DataContext.clickcommand}.. Assuming your hub element dstacontext refers to MsinPageVM. Let me know whether it works

Comment: Not working, as the ElementName is not found, although I renamed it. I think you are right the DataContext of DataTemplate is different. But why? Is this the default behavior?

Comment: If I Bind the command to a codebehind method, it works. But not in the ViewModel...

Comment: Yup. You have to set DataContext properly. Can you post the xaml with ElementName?

Comment: Can you tell me to which element did you set DataContext as MsinPageVM( Your view model)

Comment: So DataContext of hub is not your view model. Then give name to your Page element and use that. Or In code behind set DataContext of Hub element to your View model. It will work

Comment: As of now how are you setting view model to your Page? Please post that code

Comment: What are you trying to do with the RelativePanel inside the GridView? Shouldn't it be wrapped in <GridViewItem> or <GridView.ItemTemplate> ?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to bind the click event on a GridView/ListView I always follow this tutorial (here is the link: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/how-to-bind-the-itemclick-event-to-a-command-and-pass-the-clicked-item-to-it/)

First you have to create a class that define an attached property:

```
public static class ItemClickCommand 
{ 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), 
    typeof(ItemClickCommand), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject d, ICommand value) 
    { 
       d.SetValue(CommandProperty, value); 
    }

    public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject d) 
    { 
        return (ICommand)d.GetValue(CommandProperty); 
    }

    private static void OnCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var control = d as ListViewBase; 
        if (control != null) 
            control.ItemClick += OnItemClick; 
    }

    private static void OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var control = sender as ListViewBase; 
        var command = GetCommand(control);

        if (command != null && command.CanExecute(e.ClickedItem)) 
            command.Execute(e.ClickedItem); 
    } 
}
```

Then in XAML simply use it in this way (It works on both ListView/GridView):

```
helpers:ItemClickCommand.Command="{Binding Click}
```

where `helpers` is the namespace in which you have defined the attached property

In your viewmodel then, define the command:

```
private RelayCommand<MyItem> click; 
public RelayCommand<MyItem> Click
{ 
    get
    { 
        if (click== null) 
        { 
            click= new RelayCommand<MyItem>( 
                (item) => 
                {                            
                    //do something with your item 
                }); 
        }

        return click; 
    } 
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not the ItemView, I have also tried to bind the Click on a Button (inside the DataTemplate) but that is also not working. So I guess somehow the DataContext is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think your view model is binded to hubsection DataContext  so it works when you put command to HubSectionHeaderClicked event. So try this

Use this binding

```
 {Binding ElementName=section1,Path="DataContext.clickcommand}
```

Let me know whether it works